# How do I change the 'after sign in path' for a user that has been authenticated with a token with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have overwritten after_sign_in_path_for in my application controller as follows:

**application_controller.rb**

```
def after_sign_in_path_for resource
  case resource
    when User
        blah
    when Admin
        blah
  end
end
```

This works when the user signs in via the sign in page. But `after_sign_in_path_for` method doesn't get called at all when a user is signed in via [Devise's](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) [Token Authenticatable](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/TokenAuthenticatable) module. The user gets taken to the `root_path`. How can I change this?

I'm using Rails 3.2.0, ruby 1.9.3p194 and Devise 2.1.2.

Comment: Does something like this work?  `def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    session[:resource_return_to] || super
  end`

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to take a look at [Devise's own ConfirmationsController](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb), it looks to me like its calling after_sign_in_path_for, and the resource would be user I would assume. But it may take overriding that Controller with your own, so you could log the resource before you'll know for sure.